# Why can't I get a psql prompt on the command line?

Tags: postgresql, psql

It is my understanding, from reading docs for longer than I want to admit, that when I download and install the PostgreSQL binary, I should be able to do something like this:

```
sudo -i -u postgres
psql
...
psql> createdb myGnarlyDB
```

Instead what I am seeing is this:

```
sudo -i -u postgres <-- works and sends me to postgres directory
psql                <-- does not work for some reason and outputs the below

psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
      Is the server running locally and accepting
      connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Can somebody please explain to me how to get this local server going so I can get psql running in the command line and make a database?

Comment: Did you *start* Postgres? Did you have a look at the other questions here mentioning that error message? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=postgresql+domain+socket+%22%2Ftmp%2F.s.PGSQL.5432%22%3F

Comment: Lets start with your operating system, version, how you installed PostgreSQL and from where. Perhaps then some more useful guidance can be offered.

Comment: Good point. I used homebrew on OSX 10.9.4.

Comment: @kurofune right-o, so did you follow the instructions homebrew provides after installation to create the database and set PostgreSQL to start up? (I think there's a "brew info" command or something that shows it too; I don't use OS X and Apple don't permit virtual machines so it's guesswork for me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and the solution was basically to *restart my computer* and because My brew setup did not configure my path or anything, I had to use my user account to create a new postgres superuser and shuffle a few directories around in my file system to make the interface stop yelling things like

`unable to change directory to /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3: No such file or directory`

at me. It wasn't fun, but everything is working as it should. Thanks everyone for commenting and helping me troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your installation of PostgreSQL is not listening on the UNIX domain socket /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432?  Perhaps you need to try `psql -h localhost` or `psql -h 127.0.0.1`?

Are you sure that PostgreSQL is running?  Are you sure that it's configured to allow access through Unix domain sockets (that is entries in your filesystem --- they show up with a leading "s" in the "mode" column on `ls -l` ... on Unix-like systems).

Comment: When I type ls -l, nothing with a leading s comes up, so I guess not. And yes, I have tried using -h localhost, etc. Looking at similar questions on stack. I'm realizing that this is not a straightforward problem and am going for a reinstall.

Comment: @kurofune There's no evidence a reinstall is warranted or useful at this point. Don't leap ahead to that. Try to solve the issue step by step.